# jQuery selecting text from a div with :not

Tags: jquery

I have made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hAzJq/

How can i select the text inside the div but not inside the span?

```
alert($("div").not('span').text());​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.contents` first, which will extract both text nodes and HTML nodes, and apply a `:not` selector to filter out the `span`:

```
alert($("div").contents(':not(span)').text())​​​​​​​​​​​​;
```

That said, an easier way might be to apply a different `span` with a special class around just the content you do want, and select that.

Answer (score 1):

Get all the contents from the `div` using `contents()` method and then filter out what you don't need.

```
$("div").contents().filter(function(){ return !$(this).is('span');}).text();
```

You can also pass the selector to `contents()` method.

```
alert($("div").contents(':not(span)').text());​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/hAzJq/1/

References:

- `contents()` - http://api.jquery.com/contents/
- `filter()` - http://api.jquery.com/filter/