# Change div text when div contains other elements

Tags: jquery, html, replace

We came across the following situation while trying to make changes to a web page.

```
<div id="div1">
   Welcome <button id="clicker">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

This of course is just a basic example of what we ran into.  All we want to do is change the text of the `div` without losing the `button`.  For example, instead of **Welcome**, we'd like it to say **Hi**.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this with `jQuery`?  I've tried using `.replace` but that didn't seem to work.

```
$("#div1").text().replace("Welcome", "Hi");
```

**Update**

Thank you everybody for such a quick response and great answers. Responses from gdoron and mblase75 worked great.  For simplicity, mblase75 seemed to be the easist to implement but gdoron went out of his way to explain line by line.  Thank you again so much!

Comment: Is wrapping the "Welcome " in a `span` a problem?

Comment: See also similar question [jQuery selecting text from a div with :not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739609/jquery-selecting-text-from-a-div-with-not/9739675).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KaAAZ/1/ exactly for your need.

Comment: I should have mentioned that Petr.  The code is like the above.  No spans at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to use the callback function for [`.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2):

```
$('#div1').html(function(i,old) {
    return old.replace('Welcome','hi');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VsAZu/

Comment: I'll Upvote you (though it's an **excellent** answer anyway!) just to revert the anonymous downvoter nasty actions!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#div1').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3 &&
           this.data == "Welcome"; // Or this.data.indexof("Welcome") != -1
}).each(function(){
        this.data = "HI";
    });
```

What it does? Let's get in phases:

1. `$('#div1').contents()` select all the content of the `div1` div.
2. `.filter(function() { return this.nodeType == 3 && this.data == "Welcome";` filter it by two parameters the node is "textnode-3" and that data it holds is "Welcome".
3. `.each(function(){ this.data = "HI"; });` Change each Welcome to "HI"

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ncfna/1)**

Comment: @gdoron or mblase + 1 from my end! that should compensate, lol for my one I had js fiddle but no code down voted twice damn :) (deleted my post now) ouch, no idea why; even though solution was **correct**. BTW any idea why I was down-voted? for me to understand? cheers

Comment: @Tats_innit. I don't know, I truly hope that it wasn't one of the guys that answered!

Comment: @gdoron thanks for the reply man - this was my jsfiddle - jsfiddle.net/KaAAZ/1 - Can you please see (Peer review please) if I did something terribly wrong; Cheers again for your ping back :)

Comment: @Tats_innit. ohhh. You changed his DOM structure..., The `Welcome` text in his markup isn't inside a `<span>`. If this was the case, it was very easy... so yes it's terribly wrong. **=)**

Comment: @gdoron aha saweet bruv (roger that) - thank-you! Legend +1 cheers

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
var el = $('#div1');
el.html( el.html().replace('Welcome', 'Hi') );
```

But that's a bit gross, yes? Better to make stuff you need to modify have their own DOM element.

```
<div id='div1'>
  <span class='welcome_text'>Welcome</span>
  <button id='clicker'>Click Me</button>
</div>

$('#div1 span.welcome_text').text('Hi');
```

Comment: I truly hope that it's not you who downvoted all the others good and working answers. I'm sorry, but you're the only one that didn't got downvoted...

Comment: I'm sorry that I suspected you. those mysterious down-votes without a comment, I hate them!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't elegant, but couldn't you just do:

```
$("#div1").html('Hi <button id="clicker">Click Me</button>');
```

Or I imagine you could structure the markup so that the "Welcome" part had a span wrapped around it like so:

```
<span id="welcome">Welcome</span><button id="clicker">Click Me</button>
```

And target it that way.

Comment: You just didn't answer the question at all!

Comment: The first option is irrelevant. and the second option only offers an alternative.